# Unity C# Random Unique Number

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

I want to generate random unique number. These are codes:

```
public int NewNumber(int r) {
    int[] numbers = new int[r];   
    int a = Random.Range (0, r);
    if(numbers.Contains(a)) {
        a = Random.Range (0, r);
    }
    return a;
}
```

When the NewNumber(5) works ten times, I get result as like: `5,4,3,4,1,2,4,2,5,3`

But what I want: `5,3,4,2,1`

Where is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "when the NewNumber(5) works ten times"?

Comment: You say when it run 10 times, you get 10 result. So, run it 5 times maybe? Please detail your problem.

Comment: Why would you use Random to get a specific sequence of numbers?

Comment: And note that you're creating a new array in each call... so it's not going to know what it's previously returned...

Comment: Oh, are you trying to get a random number with the number (r) passed into the NewNumber method being the only number you don't want to return?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D how can achieve this, I dont get it.

Comment: @vgSefa **TR:** kardeş hayır yapmak istediğim o fonksiyon ardarda 5 kere çalıştığında 5, 1den 5 e kadar 5 farkl ıdeğer vermesi. **EN:** no bro, what I want is to get 5 different values when this functions work

Comment: He's trying to generate 5 numbers where each subsequent call to the randomizer returns a number that hasn't been returned before.

He wants a randomly distrubted set of 5 numbers, e.g. 15324 42153 etc

Comment: @Ryios yes, exactly like you said.

Comment: So you know you'll have every digit from `r` to `1`.  Why dont you just build a list of those numbers, then randomize it?  This approach doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nexx is right but you're still going to get duplicates unless you wrap this in a loop, something like...

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

public int NewNumber(int r) {

    int a = 0;

    while(a==0){    
        a = Random.Range (0, r);
        if(!numbers.Contains(a)) {
            numbers.Add(a);
        }else{
            a=0;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting your holder every time you call NewNumber method, you need to put your holder outside your method.

```
int[] numbers = new int[r];   
 public int NewNumber(int r) {
    int a = Random.Range (0, r);
    if(!numbers.Contains(a)) {
        a = Random.Range (0, r);
    }
    return a;
}
```

It will be better if you use a list instead of array;

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
public int NewNumber(int r) {
   int a = Random.Range (0, r);
   if(!numbers.Contains(a)) {
       numbers.Add(a);
   }
   return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's only one number within the range that you don't want to be returned, the solution needs no array. Instead simply repeat creating a new random number if the random number happens to be the one you don't want.

```
public int RandomNumberInRangeExcluding(int range, int excludedNumber)
{
    int r = excludedNumber;
    while (r == excludedNumber)
    {
        r = Random.Range(0, range);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you only random once when `numbers` contains `a`. Try changing `if` to `while` so the random continues until `numbers` doesn't contain `a`

```
int[] numbers = new int[r];   
public int NewNumber(int r) {
    int a = Random.Range (0, r);
    while(numbers.Contains(a)) { // change this to while
        a = Random.Range (0, r);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this achieves the same result, without waiting for `Random` to hopefully spit out whichever numbers are needed

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> rands = GetRandoms(10);
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> GetRandoms(int size)
    {
        List<int> rands = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
        {
            rands.Add(i);
        }

        return rands.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid());
    }
```